# R rbind varying number of data frames

Tags: r, rbind

I need to rbind varying number of datasets (data frames).
Currently I have this:

```
dom.ready.dat <- rbind(dom.ready.dat.bad1,
                       dom.ready.dat.bad2,
                       dom.ready.dat.bad3,
                       dom.ready.dat.bad4,
                       dom.ready.dat.bad5,
                       dom.ready.dat.bad6,
                       dom.ready.dat.bad7,
                       dom.ready.dat.bad8,
                       dom.ready.dat.bad9,
                       dom.ready.dat.bad10,
                       dom.ready.dat.good1,
                       dom.ready.dat.good2,
                       dom.ready.dat.good3,
                       dom.ready.dat.good4,
                       dom.ready.dat.good5,
                       dom.ready.dat.good6,
                       dom.ready.dat.good7,
                       dom.ready.dat.good8,
                       dom.ready.dat.good9,
                       dom.ready.dat.good10)
```

However, I might have more than 10 data frames so I need to refer to the pattern dom.ready.dat* dynamically adding the suffix dynamically to some function in R that gets varying number of parameters and assign a function like rbind on all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can specify the `pattern` in `ls` to get all the objects that were created in the global environment as a string, then use `mget` to get the values in the objects as a `list`.  From there, either use `rbindlist` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern="^dom.ready.dat")))
```

---

Or use `rbind`

```
do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern="^dom.ready.dat")))
```

---

A better option would be to read all the files in a `list` and then `rbind` instead of creating lots of objects.

```
files <- list.files(pattern="somepattern.csv", full.names=TRUE)

library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(files, fread))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating the data.frames through `lapply()` you can pipe the resulting list through to `rbind_all` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

lapply(1:20, function(i){
  read.csv(sprintf("some_file%s.csv", i))
}) %>%
   rbind_all
```

This way you don't have the intermediate step of 20 different data.frames if you're only interested in the combined.